# regularity for viscosity solutions of second order parabolic equations

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde, regularity, viscosity-solutions

I would like to  know  whether viscosity solutions to  $u_{t} -  F( D^{2} (u) )  = 0$  are  $C^{1, \alpha}$  analogous to the elliptic  case as in the book by Caffarelli and Cabre .

Here  F is  assumed to be uniformly  elliptic .

$D^{2}(u)$ is the spatial Hessian of $u$.

An answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The result holds true in the parabolic case for  F uniformly elliptic.

For a proof, you can take a look at the series of papers by Lihe Wang
where boundary regularity is also investigated: 
http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/cpa.3160450202/full
(SECTION 4)
http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/cpa.3160450103/abstract

See also https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183555461 
and the very interesting book of Krylov
http://www.springer.com/us/book/9781402003349.

Comment: Is there some hope to have that for all $t\in[0,T]$, the function $x\mapsto u(t,x)$ is analytic ?